# my json parser for jsonarry just get the first element

Tags: java, android

i have parser function that parse json array and return arrays that i use it in  a list adapter and then the adapter is used by a recyclerview .it's giving me the actual length but only the first element of the arrays is filled while the others return NULL

that is my code

```
 public void parsee_item() {
    JSONObject jsonObject = null;
    try {
        jsonObject = new JSONObject(json);
       final JSONArray userss = jsonObject.getJSONArray(JSON_ARRAY);
        item_id = new String[userss.length()];
        item_owner = new String[userss.length()];
        item_images = new String[userss.length()];
        item_names = new String[userss.length()];
        item_price = new String[userss.length()];
        item_place = new String[userss.length()];


        JSONObject jo = null;
        for (int i = 0; i < userss.length();i++) {
            jo = userss.getJSONObject(i);
            Log.d("alrsp", jo.toString());
            item_id[i] = jo.getString(KEY_ID);
            item_owner[i] = jo.getString(KEY_OWNER);
            item_images[i] = jo.getString(KEY_IMAGE);
            item_names[i] = jo.getString(KEY_NAME);
            item_price[i] = jo.getString(KEY_PRICE);


        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

the json is

```
   {
    "result": [{
        "item_id": "10",
        "owner": "user",
        "item_type_id": "1",
        "url1": "http:\/\/localhost:8080\/market\/items\/14.1.png",
        "name": "jc",
        "price": "76"
    }, {
        "item_id": "12",
        "owner": "user",
        "item_type_id": "1",
        "url1": " http:\/\/localhost:8080\/market\/items\/14.1.png",
        "name": "nzbsbsb",
        "price": "0"
    }, {
        "item_id": "13",
        "owner": "user",
        "item_type_id": "1",
        "url1": " http:\/\/localhost:8080\/market\/items\/14.1.png",
        "name": "uygf",
        "price": "0"
    }]
}
```

and this screenshot of the list
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y4jbt.png)

Comment: have you tried to change your for loop to
 
"for (int i = 0; i < userss.length();i++)"   and remove the i++ from the inner block.

Comment: change `jo = userss.getJSONObject(4);` to `jo = userss.getJSONObject(i);`

Comment: sorry i just did this for testing purpose but this is the actual code

Comment: Please add the sample json in the question.

Comment: debug and check size of array, if its more than 1, then check you adapter class getCount()

Answer (score 2):

it's not suggested parsing json yourself ,use a Json Parse Util such as [Gson](https://github.com/google/gson) or [fastJson](https://github.com/alibaba/fastjson)  instead .

Comment: @OP Never roll things yourself unless you specifically need to, the community as a whole tends to be quite smarter than any individual.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

I used your code, debug, and found values are updated their is no error with JSON paring, So check your recycler view adapter code or share it

Answer (score 0):

**Replace this line**

```
jo = userss.getJSONObject(4);
```

**with this**

```
jo = userss.getJSONObject(i);
```

Comment: sorry i just did this for testing purpose but this is the actual code

Comment: could share your json?

Answer (score 0):

```
     JSONObject jo = null;
    for (int i = 0; i < userss.length();i++) {
        jo = userss.getJSONObject(i);
        Log.d("alrsp", jo.toString());
        item_id[i] = jo.getString(KEY_ID);
        item_owner[i] = jo.getString(KEY_OWNER);
        item_images[i] = jo.getString(KEY_IMAGE);
        item_names[i] = jo.getString(KEY_NAME);
        item_price[i] = jo.getString(KEY_PRICE);
        item_place[i] = jo.getString("place");


    }
```

Comment: sorry i just did this for testing purpose but this is the actual code

Answer (score 0):

i was receiving a parameter that wasn't being sent by the jsonarray

```
item_place[i] = jo.getString("place")
```

Answer (score 0):

the problem with ur code is you use hardcode value 4

> ```
>         jo = userss.getJSONObject(4);
> ```

insted of this use

```
    jo = userss.getJSONObject(i);
```

at each and every time you are parsing the index 4 jsonObject information

```
public void parsee_item() {
    JSONObject jsonObject = null;
    try {
        jsonObject = new JSONObject(json);
       final JSONArray userss = jsonObject.getJSONArray(JSON_ARRAY);
        item_id = new String[userss.length()];
        item_owner = new String[userss.length()];
        item_images = new String[userss.length()];
        item_names = new String[userss.length()];
        item_price = new String[userss.length()];
        item_place = new String[userss.length()];


    JSONObject jo = null;
    for (int i = 0; i < userss.length();) {
        jo = userss.getJSONObject(i);
        Log.d("alrsp", jo.toString());
        item_id[i] = jo.getString(KEY_ID);
        item_owner[i] = jo.getString(KEY_OWNER);
        item_images[i] = jo.getString(KEY_IMAGE);
        item_names[i] = jo.getString(KEY_NAME);
        item_price[i] = jo.getString(KEY_PRICE);
        item_place[i] = jo.getString("place");
        i++;

    }
} catch (JSONException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

}

if you use this type of parsing it may lead to null pointer exception

Answer (score 0):

You can parse above JSON as follows

```
private void jsonParse(String response) throws JSONException {
        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
        JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("result");
        if (jsonArray != null && jsonArray.length() > 0) {
            for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject object = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                if (object != null) {
                    String itemId = object.getString("item_id");
                    String owner = object.getString("owner");
                    String item_type_id = object.getString("item_type_id");
                    String url1 = object.getString("url1");
                    String name = object.getString("name");
                    String price = object.getString("price");
                }
            }
        }
    }
```